# Finding the region of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be the directed line from $(-1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$ and $B$ be the curve which starts at (1,1) and moves along $x^2+y^2=2$ up to $(-1,-1)$. Let $C$ be the union of $A$ and $B$ and $R$ be the region enclosed by $C$.

Use Greens theorem to compute the line integral of $xy$ d$x$ over $R$.

I can't see what the region $R$ should be though.

Comment: It is the region enclosed by the a semicircle that starts in the first quadrant and ends in the third quadrant.

Comment: it is a half circle

Comment: As specified in this post, the semicircle might be "above or below" the line $y=x$ (which might make a difference).

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $\{(x,y):(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2\}$ describes a circle of center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$. In particular, $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 = 2\}$ is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and center $(0,0)$ which passes through $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. Now since $(-1,-1),(0,0),(1,1)$ are on the line-segment $A$, it must be a diameter of the circle.

See the red area on the figure below.

[image]

Can you continue from here ?

Comment: $-{\sqrt{2}}<x<0$ and $x<y<{\sqrt{2}}$ is the region?

Comment: no, it's $\{(\sqrt 2\cos\theta,\sqrt 2\sin\theta)\mid \theta\in[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}]\}$. What you propose is a triangle.

Comment: ok so how would I do the integral now that I have 'lost' my x and y?

Comment: If $\{(x,y)\mid (x,y)\in A\}=\{\gamma(\theta)\mid \theta\in B\}$ then $$\int_{A}fd\ell=\int_{B}f(\gamma (\theta))\dot\gamma (\theta)d\theta$$ with $A$ a curve and $B=\gamma(A)$

Comment: ok so maybe I should use $0<r<{\sqrt{2}}$, ${\pi}/4<{\theta}<5{\pi}/4$ and put $x=rcos{\theta}, y=rsin{\theta}$? Right?

Comment: no because you don't use it on $$\iint_R \text{rot}(f)dxdy$$ but on $\int_{C}fd\ell$ (because $\iint_R fdxdy=\int_C fd\ell$ by green theorem).